# Store DateTime in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, core-data

```
@IBOutlet weak var Datetime: UITextField!

let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

func createDatePicker()

{

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target:nil,action: #selector(donePressed))

    toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)

    Datetime.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    Datetime.inputView = datePicker

}
newEvent.setValue(formater.stringFromDate(Datetime), forKey: "eventDateTime")
```

hey guys i am getting  date and time in a textfield through date picker.how can i submit it to core data

Comment: It would be better if you saved the time stamp which is double

Comment: how can i do that ? can u suggest me

Comment: CoreData supports `Date` types natively.   Get the date from your datepicker and put it straight into core data